# Remover todas listas dentro de lista que tenham o valor igual 'A01' retornando a posição que estavam

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista dentro de lista e preciso remover todos valores iguais a 'A01', porém preciso saber a posição dos itens que foram removidos...

A lista original era assim:

```
valuesTag = [['A01'], ['A01'], ['A03'], ['A04'], ['A05']]
```

Depois encontrei um jeito de filtrar:

```
tagFiltered = [item for item in valuesTag if item != ['A01']]
```

Retornando:

```
[['A03'], ['A04'], ['A05']]
```

Mas ainda não sei como pegar a posição dos itens que foram removidos...

Comment: É isso: https://ideone.com/fHqYk3 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nesse caso você poderia fazer assim:

```
tagValues = [['A01'], ['A01'], ['A03'], ['A04'], ['A05']]
tagFiltered = [item for item in tagValues if item != ['A01']]

# Acrescentei essa variável
deletedTags = [indice for indice, item in enumerate(tagValues) if item not in tagFiltered]
```

Dessa forma você terá as posições dos itens deletados.

P.S. Atualizei o nome da variável valuesTag para tagValues, pois acredito que todas as variáveis ficaram com o mesmo padrão.

Comment: Para descobrir a posição basta adaptar um pouco o código que você já fez. Se quiser editar sua resposta e colocar ```deletedTags = [indice for indice, item in enumerate(tagValues) if item not in tagFiltered]```, acho que seria o suficiente para ser aceito. Um abraço e boa sorte.

Comment: Mesmo que siga a sugestão acima, ainda é um algoritmo ineficiente. Primeiro tem um loop pra montar a lista `tagFiltered`. Depois, outro loop pra montar `deletedTags`, mas para cada item da lista original, o operador `in` percorre novamente a lista `tagFiltered` para ver se o elemento está lá. No pior dos casos, é um algoritmo quadrático (no caso médio, será bem próximo disso). Não precisa de nada disso, pois [dá pra fazer em um único loop](https://ideone.com/fHqYk3). Claro, não vai mais usar as list comprehensions, mas nem toda solução fica melhor com elas.

Comment: é interessante saber se não é um [problema xy](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy).

Comment: @Juven_v por isso que não posso dar o +1. Mesmo a resposta resolvendo o problema não é a melhor das abordagens pois tem complexidade de tempo O(n²) quando o problema pode (é para ser) ser resolvido em O(n).

Comment: E se agora se eu precisasse remover as posições que pegamos de outra lista?